# Regeneration of sine wave using microcontroller

Tags: embedded, microcontroller

I don't have much knowledge about microcontrollers. In my project, I need to shift the sine wave. Here, I want to know, if I feed pure sine at port A pin 2. Then, will i get the shifted version of pure sine wave at port B pin 2 . will the following instruction work?

```
Inialise port A as input and port B as output 
call delay
portb=porta
```

we can generate sine wave using DAC in microcontroller. But, as it is not perfect, it wont meet required conditions.

Comment: The pin specification is entirely useless information without knowing what the device is!  And without knowing what the "required conditions" are, it is hard to advise on that.  Generally the application of a low pass filter with cut-off frequency <= sample-rate/2 and > the signal frequency is required to remove quantisation noise.

Comment: This is potentially a reasonable question, address the criticisms and make it clear and perhaps it will avoid further down votes or closure.

Answer (score 2):

First of all the input needs to be to an ADC, and the output needs to be from a DAC (or a PWM with appropriate output filtering).  It is not clear from your question that the pins you have chosen are appropriate for that.

If you are generating the sine from the DAC, why would you apply it to an input only to output it again?  If you need two sine waves shifted in phase, why not simply generate calculated outputs from two DAC or PWM?  Either way you need two analogue outputs, but that way you do not need any input.  A PWM will need greater analogue filtering than a DAC and is likely to support lower bandwidth, but most microcontroller have more PWMs than DACs.

You cannot simply call a delay than copy port a to port b, that would be simply be a copy of a to b after a delay.  You need to take samples from A and place then in a FIFO buffer, then apply the output of the FIFO to B.  The length of the FIFO determines the delay.

Comment: Shifting an existing sinewave is very different from generating two with a phase relationship.

Comment: It is, but the question suggests generating the signal from the microcontroller's *own* DAC, feeding it back into the *same* microcontroller (I assume - it is ambiguous), shifting it then outputting the shifted signal. If the source of the original signal and the shifted signal are the same, then the source would do better to generate both signals directly.  Using the DAC-to-ADC feedback introduces sampling/conversion delay, introduces environmental noise and non-linearity distortion and ties up an ADC. I am trying to make sense of a very badly formulated question here.

Comment: No, nothing in the question suggests that the signal originates in the microcontroller.

Comment: @ChrisStratton:  You think?  That is exactly whet "*we can generate sine wave using DAC in microcontroller.*" suggests to me.  That might mean a *different* microcontroller or it might refer to the output to "port B", but neither seems likely, and in the latter case that would not be *generating* the sine wave, but replicating the input signal.  My answer was as much to point out the ambiguity in the question as anything else.  So far this is a good starting point for [The Swing Project](http://www.jacobsen.no/anders/blog/archives/images/project.html), and this is frame two. ;)

Comment: Thank you for replying to my question. But, here, I don't want to generate sine wave using DACs or ADCs present in microcontroller. It wont be as pure as the one generated from function generator. As, I want phase shift, I was thinking to feed the sine wave from function generator to any port (suppose port A of atmega8) and will write the above mentioned code to uc. Doing so, will I get pure sine wave as original one at output port ( here, port B) and with phase delay? as mentioned above, will FIFO buffer shift the wave??

Comment: @user1905967:  In that case you should really make that clear in your question.  Perhaps remove any mention of the DAC. I am posting another answer rather than explaining this in comments.

Comment: The DAC is quite obviously there to output the *shifted* waveform.

Comment: The phrase "generate sine wave" was used. The word "Generate" implies that it is the source rather than the output.  Using the DAC to output the shifted input is simply copying, not generating - if the input were not a sine neither would the output be. I accept that this answer is not what the OP intended, but it is an answer to precisely what he appeard to be asking. Now the OP has responded with a clarification, I have posted another answer.  It seems clear however that the OP is under some significant misunderstanding regarding the nature of MCU I/O and digital signal processing.

Answer (score 1):

A microcontroller is not an analogue device, you cannot put in an analogue signal on just any old pin and and transfer that signal to another pin. Most pins are digital GPIO, they except just two states representing 0 or 1.  No matter what voltage you apply, it will be interpreted as either high or low.

Rather you will have to use an ADC input, sample at sufficiently high frequency, delay the samples through a FIFO, then apply the delayed samples to a DAC.  Reconstruction of a "pure" sine wave from the quantized DAC output requires analogue filtering circuitry.  With a filter cut-off lower than half the sampling rate you will recover a reasonably good representation of the original signal (which can be any signal with components below half the sampling frequency - it need not be a sine wave).  If you do use a more complex signal, you will need to analogue filter the input to remove components above half the sampling rate to avoid aliasing.

It might be possible to do all that on one chip using a [Cypress PSoC](http://www.cypress.com/psoc/), since these are hybrid chips with reconfigurable analogue elements as well as a microcontroller.